# How to run script and catch its return value

Tags: powershell

I have this simple function that return some value based on the passed argument:

```
function GetParam($fileName)
{
    if($fileName.ToLower().Contains("yes"))
    {
        return 1
    }
    elseif($fileName.ToLower().Contains("no"))
    {
        return 2
    }
    else
    {
        return -1
    }     
}
```

I want to call this script from another script and get its return value, in order to decide what to do next.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *dot source* the script where the `GetParam` function is defined to expose it to the other script:

**getparam.ps1**

```
function GetParam($fileName)
{
    if($fileName.ToLower().Contains("yes"))
    {
        return 1
    }
    elseif($fileName.ToLower().Contains("no"))
    {
        return 2
    }
    else
    {
        return -1
    }     
}
```

**other.ps1**

```
. .\getparam.ps1 # load the function into the current scope.
$returnValue = GetParam -fileName "yourFilename"
```

**Note:** Consider using [approved Verbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx) and change your function name to `Get-Param`. Also you can omit the return keyword.